# Why np.unint8 and np.int8 free up memory while any other numpy format does not?

Tags: python, numpy, garbage-collection

I am working on a project where I am reading a huge bunch of images and where I'm struggling with memory management. I was reading the images using int32/float32 format (I know the default format should be uint8, but I wanted to check using others since I am going to fusion different kinds of data that might be from different types).

For freeing up the memory I am deleting the heavy objects that I am not using after I have read all the images. For it, i am using del and explicitly calling the garbage collector:

```
del object
gc.collect()
```

Here is where the weird stuff starts. If I use **np.int32 or np.float32** (for instance `np.zeros((598, 598, 3), dtype=np.int32)` as dtype for the arrays, the memory doesn't free up, as it can be observed in the image below:

[image]

However, if I use as dtype **np.uint8 or np.int8** the memory does free up, as it can be observed in the image below:

[image]

I have also noticed that if I limit the number of images that I am reading (up to 8.61 GB of memory) the memory does free up. The two cases can be observed in the images below:
[image]
[image]

Why does this might be happening?
Thank you all in advance!